# In jquery, how can I write a function to copy the height of one DIV to another DIV once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net

Consider the following,

```
<div id="outerDIV">
     <div id="innerDIV" style="height: 100%;">
         <asp:ContentPlaceHolder... />
     </div>
</div>
```

These DIVs reside in the master page of an asp.net site.  I would like to write a function that copies the innerDIV's height and apply it to the outerDIV's height.  I can do this normally, like so:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#outerDIV').height($('#innerDIV').height());
    });
```

but the problem is I only want it to occur at the first load of the page. When the user navigates away to other pages, I don't want the outerDIV to resize again.

How may I accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: Use cookies. Set a cookie and test it at the load

Comment: In other words, you do not want to declare this script in the master page, and only apply it to the first content page, right?

Comment: Then don't include the script in all of your pages

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why don't you use `cookies`.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if(!$.cookie("setHeight"))
        {
           $('#outerDIV').height($('#innerDIV').height());
           $.cookie("setHeight", "1");
        }
    });
```

And delete the cookie whenever you want using `$.removeCookie("setHeight");`

Comment: Very important read: [cookies vs localStorage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220660/local-storage-vs-cookies).  In short, don't set cookies unless server needs to see them!

Comment: Like Jaxo said, you should not be using cookies for something you can control client side with HTML classes and jQuery selectors.

Answer (score 1):

From the MDN [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/):
Use a class selector in conjunction with your ID selector.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
         $('#outerDIV.firstpage').height($('#innerDIV.firstpage').height());
     }
 });
```

By adding the `class='firstpage'` selector, you can differentiate between your first page and your other pages, without worrying about cookies or tracking another variable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do something like this

```
var applied = 0;/*use it to check if height to outter div has been applied */
$(document).ready(function(){

  if(applied == 0){
  $('#outerDIV').height($('#innerDIV').height());
applied = 1;
}//this way the height will be applied only once

});
```